# accessing Oracle data from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008

I need to import a table from an Oracle database to a table in a SQL Server 2008 Enterprise database. What is the most quick and easy solution? Could I use linked server (to link from SQL Server 2008 to Oracle) to select * from Oracle table, and insert them to SQL Server table? Appreciate if there is any ready to use documents.

BTW: since the Oracle table contains binary fields (BLOB), so export data in Oracle table to a text file then import text file into SQL Server may not feasible, correct?

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: ..Sounds like you have your solution...Using a Linked Server would be a fine way to handle the data transfer. The best part is you probably already understand how to use a Linked Server.  Go with it.

Comment: Hi John, I used linked server before, but not dealing with Oracle. Could you recommend me a step by step document? I am not sure if any key settings, like what kinds of driver to select? Any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two articles on creating a linked server

Using OLEDB Connection on a 32bit SQL Server
http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/setting-up-an-oracle-linked-server49687.aspx

Using ODBC on a 64bit SQL Server
http://tlingenf.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!B1B09F516B5BAEBF!216.entry

Or google "SQL Server 2008 Create Linked Server to Oracle"

Comment: Great. Perfect answer to my question too.